# I am trying to implement a rating system But I am not not able to pass the values of rating in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I gone through the documentation and I tried the following code. I am able to get the data for `enquiryDesc` but getting null values for rating. I tried several steps and getting null values.

My html form is

```
<form id="enquiryBox" method="POST" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="handelSubmit($event);">
  <div class="modal-body brbottom-20">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <fieldset class="rating">
            <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" v-bind:value="5" ><label v-bind:value="5" class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome"></label>
               <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" v-bind:value="4" ><label v-bind:value="4" class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good"></label>
               </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label>Enquiry</label>
          <textarea placeholder="Write your enquiry here" rows="7" id="enquiryDesc" name="enquiryDesc" class="form-control required" title="Desc" v-model="enquiryDesc" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <button id="btn-submit-enquiry" class="btn whiteButton" type="submit">Post Enquiry</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My vue js script is as

```
enquiryBox = new Vue({
   el: "#enquiryBox",
   data: {
     rating: '',
     enquiryDesc: '',
   },
   methods: {
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
       var vm = this;
       data = {};
       data['rating'] = this.rating;
       data['enquiryDesc'] = this.enquiryDesc;
       console.log(data);

       $.ajax({
         url: 'https://api/post/add_review/',
         data: data,
         type: "POST",
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(e) {
           if (e.status) {
             alert("Success")

           } else {
             vm.response = e;

             alert(" Failed")
           }
         }
       });
       return false;
     }
   },
 });
```

My response for `console.log(data)`

> {rating: '', enquiryDesc: "cghjl,./"}

I have used `v-model` and `v-bind:value` and now to I am not the values. I am really stuck on these. Is something not initialized? Please help me to have a solution.I have gone through several tutorials and everything says to do in the same way.

Comment: Remove the `v-binds` on the radio button values,you don't need to do that unless you are referencing a `computed` or `data` property in your Vue instance. or trying to pass a number or boolean value as a prop.

Comment: i remove v-bind still getting same result

Comment: Here, this should help, I've simply removed your `v-binds`: https://jsfiddle.net/dw36bd5n/

Comment: no sir, i am not getting in my work

Comment: In that example the radio button value is correctly bound to the value data property. Are you expecting something else to happen or are you getting an error?

Comment: You can't use v-model (two-way binding) with radio buttons in way you are tryin for.

Comment: @WaldemarIce then how can I achieve the values?

Comment: @WaldemarIce can you please help

Comment: hm. wait for example in answer.

Comment: @WaldemarIce i didnot get you What is  
hm. wait for example in answer.

Comment: I wrote an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the value attribute in inputs. For Vue is source of truth the v-model value. Just set the default v-model value and particular input will be check automatically.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      rating: 3
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(this.rating)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <form action="" method="post" @submit="send">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" v-model="rating">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" v-model="rating">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" v-model="rating">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" v-model="rating">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" v-model="rating">
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Try these changes in your code - in HTML:

```
<fieldset class="rating">
  <label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome">5</label>
  <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5">
  <label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good">4</label>
  <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4">
</fieldset>
```

And in JS:

```
enquiryBox = new Vue({
  el: "#enquiryBox",
  data: {
    rating: 5,
    enquiryDesc: '',
  },
  methods: {
    handelSubmit: function (e) {
      const vm = this
      const data = {}

      data['rating'] = this.rating
      data['enquiryDesc'] = this.enquiryDesc

      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api/post/add_review/',
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (e) {
          if (e.status) {
            alert('Success')
          } else {
            vm.response = e
            alert('Failed')
          }
        }
      })

      return false
    }
  }
})
```

Change the first line also and try it agin:

```
<form id="enquiryBox" method="post" data-parsley-validate="true" @submit="handelSubmit">
```

Comment: i remove v-bind from my value and give a default value as 3 for rating. Now, always I am getting the value 3

Comment: sorry sir, I am not able to get.. now value is always 5 which is given.. that selection is not working i think.. but i don't have any error in the console too

Comment: {rating: 5, enquiryDesc: "ghjkl"}

Comment: this is what I am getting sir

Comment: sir, why am not able to bind the values?

Comment: but value is always 5

Comment: When I use <select> I am able to change values <select class="dropdown" v-model="rating"> <option v-bind:value="0">Your rating</option> <option v-bind:value="1">1.Poor</option> </select>   WHAT IS THE PROBLEM WITH <RADIO BUTTON>

Comment: I dont know. In the example in my answer the radio buttons works as expected. I font understand why you are not able to achieve the same functionality with your code.